# C# mongoDB Driver concurrent Insert fails

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have am trying to write records to mongodb using the C# mongo driver 2.13.2. I am calling the `Insert` method below in a loop from another class. In that class if I sleep for 5 seconds between each call to the Insert method, then all calls result in an insert. If I remove the sleep then some records get dropped. Here is the relevant code taking out the unnecessary bits.

`_collections` is a dictionary object that stores initialized collections.

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>> _collections;
```

This section is in the constructor of my class which is initialized at application startup. `db.Collections` contains a list of collection names and a way to retrieve them when required by the key. I am using the key and value from `db.Collections` to create a dictionary of initialized collections in the `_collections` variable.

```
var database = client.GetDatabase(db.Database);
foreach (var c in db.Collections)
{
   _collections.Add(c.Key, database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(c.Value));
}
```

The section below is a method in the same class, where I operate on a collection by passing in the collection key and calling the insert method

```
public async Task<bool> Insert(BsonDocument data, string collection)
{

    if (data == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    
    await _collections[collection].InsertOneAsync(data);


    return true;

}
```

Why are records failing to insert when there is no sleep? When I provide a sleep of more than 5 seconds then all iterations result in an insert.

Comment: Can you show the loop that calls `Insert`? If you are inserting a lot of records into the same collection, you could use bulk insert statements to improve performance and send only one command to MongoDB.

Comment: The loop is to actually to  simulate a load. This method is running in a background process and reads off a queue. The loop dumps into the queue. I thought of keeping the question simple to focus on where I thought the problem was..

Comment: So when there are multiple documents in the queue, it picks it up in an asynchronous way for inserts. Is this write failure due to async inserts?

Comment: Might be that the inserts are not awaited. Maybe you can add some log statements to verify that insert is called and executed till the end. Could it be that the inserts violate a unique index?

Comment: What is returned by InsertOneAsync when it fails to insert?